# Jump to ID and load dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I want to load dynamic content based on the url loaded into the page. I am doing this using the following script:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name
var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('region');
```

This works so if I have the url `demo.com/page?region=asia` it will load the specific content. However I want it to jump to the ID of the div that the content is contained in for example `demo.com/page/#countries?region=asia` when I do this it loads the dynamic content but does not jump to that section in the page where as `demo.com/page/#countries` will jump there.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.hash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could 'manually' scroll to the div by using:
`document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();`